# piping 0..10 to an advanced function

Tags: powershell

I can't work out why piping `0..10` does not come through my functions while passing it directly does.

I expect piping `0..10` to the following function would return 10 results.

```
function a{param([parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)][int[]]$t)$t|%{$_+10}}
0..10 | a
```

I do not understand why the following only returns one result.

I expected that a block of values would be piped in and `$t | %{$_+10}` would break them up, operate on them and return them to the output.

It works as expected if I run the following

```
a(0..10)
```

I don't think anything is wrong, just that I don't understand what `0..10` is and was hoping to get some help from the community.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Best way to understand this is that Advanced Functions without the

```
BEGIN {}
PROCESS {}
END {}
```

structure are very confusing when it comes to accepting from the pipeline and arrays.

What's happening here is that without the PROCESS {} block, the $T in your function is an INT[], and is passed as an array.  Your foreach processes, but returns the last result of the command - 10 + 10

Changing your code to:

```
function a{ 
   param([parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)][int[]]$t)
   BEGIN {}
   PROCESS{       
     $t | %{$_+10}
   }
   END {}
}
```

returns what you expect - each element of $T is passed to the foreach and then down the pipeline.

Here's a link from one of the MS PowerShell guys: [Windows PowerShell: The Advanced Function Lifecycle](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh413265.aspx) shows some good examples.

Reading the link from @Chris-Magnuson below, I came up with great code that shows exactly what's happening:

```
Function AA {
    Begin {"Begin: The input is $input , Pipeline is $_"}
    End   {"End:   The input is $input , Pipeline is $_" }
}

PS C:\Temp> 1,2,3 | AA
Begin: The input is  , Pipeline is 
End:   The input is 1 2 3 , Pipeline is 

Function BB {
    Begin   {"Begin:   The input is $input , Pipeline is $_" }
    Process {"Process: The input is $input , Pipeline is $_" }
    End     {"End:     The input is $input , Pipeline is $_" }
}

PS C:\Temp> 1,2,3 | BB
Begin:   The input is  , Pipeline is 
Process: The input is 1 , Pipeline is 1
Process: The input is 2 , Pipeline is 2
Process: The input is 3 , Pipeline is 3
End:     The input is  , Pipeline is 3
```

Kind of Funky, I'd say.

Comment: Thank you for your quick and comprehensive answer

Answer (score 4):

You need to add a process block to get the behavior you want:

`function a{param([parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)][int[]]$t)process{$t|%{$_+10}}}`

Without a `process {}` it is implied that all the code in the function runs in `end {}` which will only run it for the last number in your set.

The best article on this topic that I have found is [this one](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/net-tools/down-the-rabbit-hole-a-study-in-powershell-pipelines-functions-and-parameters/).

[This chart](https://www.simple-talk.com/wp-content/uploads/imported/1326-PS_functions_wallchart_1_0_1.htm) from the article summarizes everything but it took me many times of reading it before I understood it.